# Why was a 1967 Impala chosen as Dean Winchester's car in Supernatural?

Tags: props, supernatural

We have seen Dean riding on a black Impala in Supernatural. So was there any specific reason for choosing a 1967 black Impala?

Answer (score 3):

> Eric Kripke has said in interviews that he knew he wanted a classic 1960s American muscle car and was originally going to go with a 1965 Mustang, but his neighbour convinced him that the Impala would be a better choice because "you can put a body in the trunk" and "when people stop next to it at the lights, they lock their doors.

[More...](http://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/entertainment/fact-scarier-than-fiction/story-e6frexlr-1111113119827)

Comment: The link in your answer doesn't appear to work (and even after "fixing" it, it only points to the homepage of that site). Is that actually a quote from the webpage? If so, it needs to be made clearer. If not, a blockquote isn't the appropriate formatting.

Comment: @Anthony Grist : Sorry bro...i have edited the link now you can check it out.